# How to use global properties in struts.xml file in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am developing a web application in struts2. I have declared global properties in struts.xml like:

```
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="LableResources,MessageResources" />
```

How do I use those properties in struts.xml itself? I want to implement a system in which request URI names come from global properties file.

Comment: Request URI's... but that come from a properties file? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @Quaternion : take an login example here ...
         <action name="viewLoginPage"   class="com.ndil.web.login.LoginAction" method="viewLoginPage">
            <result name="success">/jsp/userLogin.jsp</result>
        </action>
Here ..I want viewLoginPage  name from message resource file.
I want to make a common file which contains all possible request URLs within the application.

Comment: To what end? Might be a lot more straight forward to go with a script which iterates over your file of urls simply calling lynx or wget depending on what you want. It's not Java but you will get a result.  If you are testing ajax, I think the json plugin is well tested so you only need to test the action and not the result same would go for xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that. I18n resources are for messages an runtime stuff not for configuration. 
You can use parameters in the configuration but at runtime they have to be available as request parameters or in the value stack.
Like this:

```
<result name="input" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">${from}</param>
                <param name="id">${id}</param>
            </result>
```